# Can other methods from a java file be called in the onCreate method in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, variables, methods, oncreate

I'm trying to call a method that is defined later in my java file:

```
public int moveHorizontal;
public int moveVertical;
public RelativeLayout relative1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    relative1 = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relative1);
    moveHorizontal = width(1f/12f);
    moveVertical = height(1f/12f);
}
```

...

```
public int width(float fraction) {
    float relativeWidth = relative1.getWidth();
    return Math.round(fraction*relativeWidth);
}
```

However, when I run my app in debug mode I see that `moveHorizontal` and `moveVertical` are both set to `0`. I know the method works fine as I've tried using it in the rest of the code to find `width(1f/12f)` and it returns `90`. Does this mean that I can't call the `width` method inside the `onCreate` method? And is there a way around this?

Comment: Have you tried debugging? Seems more likely to me that `relative1.getWidth()` is returning an unexpected value (perhaps it is not drawn yet?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does this mean that I can't call the width method inside the onCreate method?

You can call `width()`. However, `relative1.getWidth()` will be 0 at this point, because the layout has not been measured and laid out yet.

> And is there a way around this?

First, see if there is a better solution to whatever problem you are trying to solve, that involves getting the size of `relative1`. For example, `ConstraintLayout` and `LinearLayout` both support sizing things based upon fractions, without you having to do the calculations yourself.

If you are sure that you need the width and height, [wait to try using it until the widgets have been sized](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24035591/115145).